# iOS update atribute of an entity using coredata

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, ios5, iphonecoredatarecipes

here is my code to update table using core data

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UsageData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(member_id=Null)"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];
UsageData *matches;
NSError *error;

NSArray *objects=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"Object count===%d",[objects count]);

for(int i=0;i<[objects count];i++)
{
    matches=[objects objectAtIndex:i];
    UsageData *data=(UsageData *)matches;
    NSLog(@"Data before===%@",data);
    [data setMember_id:memberKey];
```

//        [data setValue:memberKey forKey:@"member_id"];

```
    [context save:&error];

    NSLog(@"Data after====%@",data);
    data=nil;
}

entityDesc=nil;
request=nil;
matches=nil;
error=nil;
objects=nil;
```

i wanted to save this changes to the database also, the logs gives the correct think but my local   sqlite database is not updated, is any one have an idea? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Do you save back the data to the database, like

```
 [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
```

?